# How to search comments based on Specific Keyword from social networks?

Tags: twitter, linkedin-api, google-plus, tumblr, instagram

Is there any social network like Google+, Instagram, Tumblr, MySpace, Linkedin, Foursquard, have Search api which allows to search public comments/posts based on "Specific Keyword".

Just like Twitter Search API, as described on these links...

[Search Twitter from your Program](http://freeze-cse.blogspot.in/2012/05/search-twitter-from-your-program.html)

[Search Twitter from Java](http://scn.sap.com/community/java/blog/2012/05/06/search-twitter-from-java)

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

You can search public posts on Facebook via the Graph API using the following URL structure:

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=batman&type=post`

You can search public tagged photos via the Instagram API like this (authentication required):

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=batman`

You can search for public tagged posts on Tumblr like this (authentication required):

`http://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?tag=batman`

You can search for public tips via the Foursquare API like this (authentication required):

`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/tips/search?ll=40.7,-74&query=batman`